# Pandas updating weekend date to nearest business day

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I have a dataframe that currently looks like this:

```
raw_data = {'AllDate':['2017-04-05','2017-04-06','2017-04-07','2017-04-08','2017-04-09']}
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(raw_data,columns=['AllDate'])
print df
```

I would like to add a WeekDate column to this dataframe such as if the date in the 'AllDate' falls on the weekend, the 'WeekDate' column has the date from the Friday before. If the date falls on the weekday, the date should remain the same.

As an example, the resulting DataFrame should look like this:

```
raw_data = {'AllDate':['2017-04-05','2017-04-06','2017-04-07','2017-04-08','2017-04-09'],'WeekDate':['2017-04-05','2017-04-06','2017-04-07','2017-04-07','2017-04-07']}
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(raw_data,columns=['AllDate','WeekDate'])
print df
```

Any ideas how I could achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
import pandas as pd
import time

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'AllDate':['2017-04-05','2017-04-06','2017-04-07','2017-04-08','2017-04-09']
})
df['WeekDate'] = [
    x if x.weekday() not in [5,6] else None for x in pd.to_datetime(df['AllDate'])
]
print(df.ffill())
```

Comment: Why the else 'Non' and using the previous value? Doesn't work in this scenario:

Comment: raw_data = {'AllDate':['2017-03-17','2017-04-16','2017-05-14','2017-06-‌​18','2017-07-18']} import pandas as pd df = pd.DataFrame(raw_data,columns=['AllDate']) print df

Answer (score 0):

This works best (adding to the answer posted by Zhe):

```
import pandas as pd
import time
from datetime import datetime,timedelta
df = pd.DataFrame({'AllDate':['2017-04-05','2017-04-06','2017-04-07','2017-04-08','2017-04-09']})
df['WeekDate'] = [x if x.weekday() not in [5,6] else x - timedelta(days = (x.weekday()-4)) for x in pd.to_datetime(df['AllDate'])]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's perhaps a simpler answer that comes up a lot dealing with timeseries, etc. Key is the offset objects available in [Pandas tseries](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html#dateoffset-objects)

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"AllDate": ["2017-04-01", "2017-04-02", "2017-04-03", "2017-04-04", "2017-04-09"]})
df["AllDate"] = pd.to_datetime(df["AllDate"])
df["PrevBusDate"] = df["AllDate"].apply(pd.tseries.offsets.BusinessDay().rollback)

df.head()
...
>>>    AllDate PrevBusDate
0   2017-04-01  2017-03-31
1   2017-04-02  2017-03-31
2   2017-04-03  2017-04-03
3   2017-04-04  2017-04-04
4   2017-04-09  2017-04-07
```

NB: Don't have to convert the 'AllDate' column if you don't want to. Can simply generate the offsets and work with them however you like, eg:

```
[pd.tseries.offsets.BusinessDay().rollback(d) for d in pd.to_datetime(df["AllDate"])]
```