# Resampling a pandas DataFrame by business days gives bad results

Tags: python, pandas

When I run the following code, the results appear to add the non-business day data to the result.

**Code**

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'id': [30820864, 32295510, 30913444, 30913445],
                   'ticket_id': [100, 101, 102, 103],
                   'date_time': [
                       '6/1/17 9:48',
                       '6/2/17 13:11',
                       '6/3/17 13:15',
                       '6/5/17 13:15'],
                   })
df['date_time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date_time'])
df.index = df['date_time']

x = df.resample('B').count()
print(x)
```

**Result**

```
            id  ticket_id  date_time  
date_time                                     
2017-06-01   1          0          1 
2017-06-02   2          0          2 
2017-06-05   1          0          1
```

I would expect that the count for 2017-06-02 would be 1 and not 2. Shouldn't the data from a non-business day (6/3/17) be ignored?

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be standard behaviour, events on weekends are grouped with friday (another [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43340488/pandas-updating-weekend-date-to-nearest-business-day/43341672) similar to this, and [here](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/11123) it says that this is convention)

One solution, drop the weekends:
`df = df[df['date_time'].apply(lambda x: x.weekday() not in [5,6])]`

Output:

```
            date_time  id  ticket_id
date_time                           
2017-06-01          1   1          1
2017-06-02          1   1          1
2017-06-05          1   1          1
```

Comment: thanks for the note. Doesn't it seem odd that this would be the default behavior? I mean, we're not rolling up on work days if non-work days are rolled into the results.

Comment: Yeah... it feels like a bit of a weird convention. But I guess 'resample' implies that all the data is still included. I find it more surprising they don't roll it into monday instead of friday. One of the git pages implies the 'B' is for 'role-back' though